# Creating a 2 dimensional array from a dat file in a function

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am trying to create a function that makes a 2-dimensional array from a dat file that is opened. I am running to errors trying to compile my program though. Below is my attempt, also my dat file has 8 columns but more rows than I can count so I am trying to create a dynamically allocating array or vector. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double Comsic_Ray_Events(vector< vector<double> > cosmic_ray, vector <double> row_vector(columns));

 int main()
 {


 return(0);
 }

void Comsic_Ray_Events(vector< vector<double> > cosmic_ray, vector <double> row_vector(columns))
{
double row = 0.;
const double columns = 8.;
ifstream cosmic_ray_data;

vector< vector<double> > cosmic_ray;
vector <double> row_vector(columns);

cosmic_ray_data.open("events_comp-h4a_10.00-10000.00PeV_zen37.00.dat", ios::in);
if(cosmic_ray_data.is_open())
{
    while(cosmic_ray_data.good())
    {
        cosmic_ray.push_back(row_vector);
        for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            cosmic_ray_data >> cosmic_ray[row][i];
            cout << setprecision(4) << cosmic_ray[row][i] << endl;
            //row++;
        }
        row++;
    }
}
else if(cosmic_ray_data.fail())
{
    cout << "File didn't open correctly" << endl;
}
cosmic_ray_data.close();
```

}

Comment: Please post the compiler errors.

Comment: You will need to show us your error messages. Also, please explain why you are unable to fix these error messages (e.g. whether you do not understand them or if there's a different reason as to why you cannot avoid them). Please elaborate on the structure of you `.dat` files as well (what kind data do they contain? How are they formatted? etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I see some design issues in your code as well with your functions, i tried to write a very simple example with your variable names more or less, hope you understand it.
First, i don't know why you try to use a void function if you write that you'd like a function that returns you a 2-dimensional vector. Second, i don't get why your function with the double return type at the beginning has the 2 vector as parameters, if that's what you wrote you want to get from the input. I can only imagine as paramater the "filename.dat" maximum. Here's the very-very simple code to achieve what you'd like:

```
vector<vector<double> > Cosmic_Ray_Events()
{
    ifstream cosmic_ray_data("events.dat");
    vector<vector<double> > cosmic_ray;
    int columns = 8;

    while(cosmic_ray_data.good())
    {
        vector <double> row_vector;
        for(int i=0; i<columns; i++)
        {
            double data;
            cosmic_ray_data >> data;
            row_vector.push_back(data);
        }
        cosmic_ray.push_back(row_vector);
    }
    cosmic_ray_data.close();

    return cosmic_ray;
}
```

Then the way you can use it:

```
vector<vector<double> > cosmic_events_vector = Cosmic_Ray_Events();
```

Beyond that, if that's not what you'd want, then be more specific plz.

Comment: This was very helpful and was what I was looking for. My only other question is how can I double check that the 2-d vector is 8 columns by n rows?

Comment: Hmm, you mentioned that you don't know exactly the number of rows in the input file, but it equals to the myvector.size() obviously, and for the columns, you can use something like this: bool check = true; for(int i=0; i<cosmic_events_vector.size(); i++) check = check && cosmic_events_vector[i].size() == 8; That way the check variable only be true if all rows have 8 columns, and please accept my answer.